# How using DNN-generated masks improve the object detection?

Tags: deep-learning, image-processing

According to this [study](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/5207-deep-neural-networks-for-object-detection.pdf), how does using DNN-based binary mask helps with localization precision and recognition of the object types in general? Does it give a better results for high-resolution object detection?